# KDL iterative IK solver joint angles not normalized

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the [arm_kinematics_tools](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_kinematics_tools) package for solving the IK of a 6DOF arm. Everything is working fine, with the little caveat that the returned joint angles are not normalized.

An example:

```
position: [577.1623005464028, 565.4397480457859, 43040.16494263808, 441.2180765483309, -17007.80488691719, 939.0145541995307]
```

If those are sent to the robot_state_publisher, the arm position is fine, implying that the angles are correct, just not normalized. I'm aware that this behavior is also related to the seed state, but I was wondering if this is normal/intended behavior of KDL and if others have experienced this too.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54634/kdl-iterative-ik-solver-joint-angles-not-normalized/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I remember seeing that too. In the package you'll find there are 3 types of the Newton-Raphson solver you can test. I found only one of them had this behaviour. The "best" of the three, with joint limits, did not.

But, for a 6 DOF robot, I'd generate an IKFast plugin. ;-)

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-02-07**:
Ah ok, thanks :) Yes, I'd do that too (re IKFast), unfortunately there are some kinematics for which closed form IK generation fails.

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-02-07**:
DRC arm or snake robot? ;-)  The basic N.R. solver is very bad.  Using KDL to make a Jacobian-based solver is one, better option.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-02-07**:
DRC arm :) See also http://openrave-users-list.185357.n3.nabble.com/Generating-IK-for-6DOF-humanoid-appendages-prototype-GFE-robot-fails-td4025593.html . Is there a Jacobian solver for KDL available?

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-02-07**:
There's functions in the KDL library to do with jacobians. I think the NASA R2 uses one, as does REEM: https://github.com/pal-robotics/reem_kinematics/blob/master/reem_kinematics_constraint_aware/src/ik_solver.cpp